# Error 500 with Angular 2 requests to Azure Websites API

Tags: javascript, azure, angular, azure-web-app-service

I am creating a Angular 2 app that connects to an API service in azure.

All API calls work when there is /api in the url :

```
this.http.get('https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/api/Init', {headers}).map(...);
```

It works also when I add authentication to a /api/InitUser call :

```
headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH', token);
```

I do get the connected user details.

But as soon as I want to access data in "/tables" I get an Error 500.

headers.append('X-ZUMO-AUTH', token);
this.http.get('https://my-app.azurewebsites.net/tables/Posts', {headers}).map(...);

I tried with :

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencode');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'x-requested-with');
```

But nothing works, I always get an error 500. I am not managing the API so I can't get the error logs right now.
If at least I would get a 401 error I would know there's something wrong in teh authentication but here I have no clue what's wrong.

Anybody has any idea how to solve this?

Comment: as you know 500 is a server error, and since you can't access the server (a big problem) what you can try to do is to setup wireshark and capture a packet you send that works and a packet that returns 500, and see their difference. from there you can work your way to make angular send the request properly.

Comment: Can you get the call to work with a tool like Postman?  If you can, then see what's different between that and the call in the network tab of chrome developer tools...  Just a stab, are you sure there's a '/tables' endpoint and it's not '/api/tables'?

Comment: As a common issue, http 500 error means that there is something wrong on the server side. You can leverage [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to generate a http request against your Easy tables scripts, to analyse the response from Mobile App server. Otherwise you can contract the Mobile App backend developer.